# swift iOS adding validation in alert textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add validation on my hardcode data which known as itemArray
Below are my screenshot that current alert view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyFhh.png)

These are my codes

```
@IBAction func adDButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        
        
        var textField = UITextField()

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Email", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
            print("Cancel button tapped")
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
        
            self.itemArray.append(textField.text!)

            self.defaults.set(self.itemArray, forKey: "EmailArray")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New Email"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)


       present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    }
```

to all swift experts, may I know is there any way for me too add validation such as alert textfield == "0" disable the add function for the users. your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: what are you looking to happen if "0" is in the field?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to happen if it does say "0"?

@IBAction func adDButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

```
    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Email", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        print("Cancel button tapped")
    }
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
        if textField.text != "0" {
             self.itemArray.append(textField.text!)

             self.defaults.set(self.itemArray, forKey: "EmailArray")

             self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
             //do something to help them like display error message
        }
        
        
    }
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New Email"
        textField = alertTextField
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(cancel)


   present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```